# Unexpected error in finding a sum of series till x terms

Tags: c++, math, sequence

This is the series I've to find the sum of (upto x terms which user inputs):

```
1/1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + ...
```

Here is the code I wrote :

```
int x;
cout << "How many terms (x) you want to add the series till?\n\n ";
cin >> x;
float m, answer=0.0;
for (int n=0; n<x; n++)
{
  m=1/((2*n)+1);
  answer=answer+m;
}
cout << " \n The answer is " << answer;
```

However, the answer always comes as 1 so what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
m=1/((2*n)+1);
```

is doing integer arithmetic on the right hand side, because all the values involved are integers.  For n=0 you get `1/((2*0)+1) = 1/1 = 1`, whereas for e.g. n=1 you get `1/((2*1)+1) = 1/3 = 0`, which is then assigned to the float.  Ultimately you get a 1 for the first term and zeroes for the rest, so the sum ends up being 1.

If you make *any* of the terms floating-point, like so:

```
m = 1.0 / (2 * n + 1);
```

then you'll get results like `1.0 / 3 = 0.333...` instead.

You can see more detail about the rules for arithmetic operators here:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: Even better (or worse!), it only takes the lone period (`.`) to completely change this behavior: replace `1` with `1.`, and woe betide anyone who loses that period sometime later. When people ask what's wrong with C family of languages, such things are a prime example.

Comment: I would make it a `1.0f` as `m` is a `float`.